# Estimating ratio of two PDFs where one of them is noisy

Tags: distributions, estimation, dataset, density-function

I have a list $L_1$ of positive integers, such as $[1, 2, 1, 3, 10, ...]$. There are repetitions. From this list, I sample (with repetition) according to some method (not relevant to my question), and get a different list of numbers $L_2$.

For each list, we can compute a "discrete $\text{PDF}$" (I'm just calling the probability mass function as PDF here), which is just the histogram having bin-size of 1.

What I want to do is to compute the ratio of these $\text{PDF}$s.

Unfortunately, $\text{PDF}_2$ is noisy, because even though I sample a large number of points (although still a few orders of magnitude lesser than $|L_1|$), some numbers have low frequency in $L_1$ itself, and hence the sampled-$\text{PDF}$ will be quite noisy for those numbers. Thus, the ratio itself will be quite noisy for those values.

Here's what I have tried:

1. I tried smoothing the $\text{PDF}$s by fitting Log-Normal and Gamma $\text{PDF}$s, however the fitting itself was not great in the region I want to estimate the ratio. Thus, this option of taking ratio of the smoothened $\text{PDF}$s is moot.
2. I tried smoothing the noisy ratio by fitting polynomial functions however polynomials don't seem to fit this curve (unless perhaps I take a very high polynomial degree). And this is pointless if the ratio values themselves are an artifact of small $\text{PDF}_1$ and $\text{PDF}_2$ values.

Are there any methods using which I can compute the ratio $\frac{\text{PDF}_1}{\text{PDF}_2}$ in a reliable manner?

Apart from this, is there a way in which I can ascertain that the ratio curve that I *have* computed isn't due to noisy small numbers in the denominator ($\text{PDF}_2$)?

Comment: This is my first question here, so please let me know if I should provide more details. New to this area :)

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about why you want to do this, but a simple solution would be just to add a small constant every value in your PMF before taking the ratio. You might also think about working with the difference in $log(PMF)$ instead of the ratio.